# PDF replacing the character mapping name with "wrong character name"

Tags: pdf, character-encoding

Hi I am trying to analyze some PDF document which displays somewhere on one of the pages money sum and currency sign after it. Graphically it represents it correctly, however when I extract text from it I notice that currency sign is replaced with "{" symbol. When looking into format I notice that indeed currency symbol (164) is replaced with "braceleft" character name, which probably causes text extractor to be confused.

```
48 0 obj
<<
  /Differences [
...
   164
    /braceleft

 254
    /.notdef
  ]
  /Type /Encoding
>>
```

The previous font definitions are as follows

```
27 0 obj
<<
  /BaseFont /SUBSET+CZOQOM0T1U42409
  /Encoding 48 0 R
  /FirstChar 32
  /FontDescriptor 49 0 R
  /LastChar 254
  /Subtype /Type1
  /Type /Font
  /Widths 50 0 R
>>
endobj

49 0 obj
<<
  /Ascent 808
  /CapHeight 600
  /Descent -221
  /Flags 6
  /FontBBox [
    -60
    -249
    1187
    808
  ]
  /FontFile3 112 0 R
  /FontName /SUBSET+CZOQOM0T1U42409
  /ItalicAngle 808
  /StemV 62
  /Type /FontDescriptor
>>
endobj
```

**Why would PDF file encoder choose to replace character name with 'braceleft' instead of using 'currency'???**

Comment: Could you share the PDF file itself? Also, you see this behavior in which exact applications?

Comment: The pdf is just a receipt which I am trying to extract information from, to be placed into say excel format for convenient information handling, it is not prepared by me. Any application which extracts text from  the pdf exhibits the same behavior. for example pdftotext.